# How to propagate JAAS security credential to server side?

Tags: jaas

The J2EE Application implementation will propagate credential to EJBContext automatically. It only includes user name instead of password, right?  What's the standard way to propagate for non-J2EE system?  I need the user/password to login another system in server side (kind of SSO).  I can put user/password into ThreadLocal. Any cons for it?

ThreadLocal won't work since authenticate and application are not same thread.  I figured out one way that put customized principal into Subject and load it from application side. Not sure if it is right approach to support SSO since the plain password is set into subject.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out one way that put customized principal into Subject and load it from application side. Not sure if it is right approach to support SSO since the plain password is set into subject.

Comment: I am interested in details about your implementation as I am in trouble with JavaEE itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213734/how-to-propagate-jaas-subject-when-calling-a-remote-ejb-rmi-over-iiop-from-a-p Regards